# Bootstrap navbar collapsed toggle displays single black line instead of menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a big problem trying to get my bootstrap navbar to display menu items when it is collapsed. I have searched all over this site and haven't found anything that works.Everything I can find either talks about jquery or bootstrap version not being implemented correctly or the collapse button being invisible. From tinkering with it I have found the problem is my custom css messes up the bootstrap css but I can't for the life of me figure out what to change to fix it.Any help is greatly appreciated.Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!--Meta -->
  <title>Navbar</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--Meta-->
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <h1 class ="navbar-brand">Navbar</h1>
    </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id ="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#homey">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#abou">About</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#porty">Portfolio</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#conty">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

</nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
  height: 125px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  position: relative!important;
  left: 100px!important;
  bottom: 10px!important;
  font-size: 4em!important;
  color: white!important;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  right: 175px;
  top: 66px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none !important;
}



@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    top: -20px !important;
    left: -10px !important;
  }
  .navbar {
    height: 70px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 30px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    bottom: 20px !important;
    left: -3px !important;
    !important;
  }
  .navbar {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 25px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 365px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 275px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
}
```

Here is a Code Pen: [Navbar](http://codepen.io/kgoode517/pen/vGVExb)

Comment: Well, I'm seeing a lot of `display:none` in your media queries, and a lot more `!important` being called. You should avoid calling `!important` like the plague and learn how to either override Bootstrap's css, or use specific identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll see what I can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a {}` actually positions it off the screen when in mobile view and its color is white, you wont be able to see it.

Therefore, I explicitly removed your positioning and color when your window enters mobile size. Also, noticed that i have commented out the `display:none` below. This should help you rethink your css a little. When in mobile view, unless you specify different css for a tag, its gonna use the one you previously specified. Try pasting this over yours and tweak it to what you need. :)

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none !important;
  }

  .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left li a {
      color: black;
      right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and I have tried your solution. However what happens when I  try your code is the menu only appears ever other click and only for a few sections at a time. Any idea why?

Comment: i dont really understand your question. what do you mean by "_ever other click and only for a few sections at a time._" ?

Comment: I think i figured out what you were trying to say. Did you forget to "comment" out the `navbar-toggle` and `navbar-collapse`? Just delete it off, if u havent. I edited the answer above.

Comment: Seconds my apologizes I had a dyslexic moment.  The menu now appears however it is unresponsive to a single click but a double click  expands the menu for about a two second period of time before it disappears.

Comment: Did you forget to "comment" out the `navbar-toggle` and `navbar-collapse`? Just delete it off, if u havent. Let me know if that was the case. :)

Comment: Thank you yes I have tried that but it has not fixed my issue. I appreciate your help however.

Comment: one last thing: remove `.navbar-collapse.collapse`. Hope that fixes things

Comment: Yes that fixed it! Thank you so much for your time and help!